# Error "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'."

Tags: android, gradle

when I try to run it this error pop up:

- Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

setting.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/..")
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "College App"
include ':app'
```